# finding name in the stl list c++

Tags: c++, stl

I'm really having a hard time on this exercise
here is the problem

Modify program 13.2 to prompt the user for a name have the program search the existing list for the entered name. If the name is in the list display the corresponding phone number; otherwise, display this message: the name is not on the phone list.

here is the code of program 13.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Nametele
{
private:
    string name;
    string phoneNum;

public:
    Nametele(string nn, string phone)
    {
        name = nn;
        phoneNum = phone;
    }

    string getName(){return name;}
    string getPhone(){return phoneNum;}
};


int main()
{
    list<Nametele> employee;
    string n;

    employee.push_front(Nametele("acme, sam", "(555) 898-2392"));
    employee.push_back(Nametele("Dolan, edith", "(555) 682-3104"));
    employee.push_back(Nametele("lanfrank, john", "(555), 718-4581"));
    employee.push_back(Nametele("mening, stephen", "(555) 382-7070"));
    employee.push_back(Nametele("zemann, harold", "(555) 219-9912"));

    employee.sort();

    cout << "the size of the list is " << employee.size() << endl;
    cout << "\n      name            telephone";
    cout << "\n--------------       ----------\n";

    while(!employee.empty())
    {
        cout << employee.front().getName()
             << "\t      " << employee.front().getPhone() << endl;
        employee.pop_front();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I really don't know how to find the elements in the list.
I'm really new to programming, especially STL so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you come up with that loop?

Comment: this loop?  while(!employee.empty())
    {
        cout << employee.front().getName()
             << "\t      " << employee.front().getPhone() << endl;
        employee.pop_front();
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard algorithm `std::find_if` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::string  name = "mening, stephen";
auto it = std::find_if( employee.begin(), employee.end(),
                        [&]( Nametele &item ) { return item.getName() == name; } );
if ( it != employee.end() ) std::cout << "Employee " << name << " is found\n";
```

Of course you should declare function getName like

```
string getName() const {return name;}
```

and within the lambda expression declare the parameter like `const Nametele &item`

If the list is sorted you can use another algorithm as for example `std::lower_bound` or `std::equal_range`
Or you can use a loop. For example

```
std::string  name = "mening, stephen";

auto it = employee.begin();
while ( it != employee.end() && it->getName() != name ) ++it;

if ( it != employee.end() ) std::cout << "Employee " << name << " is found\n";
```

Take into account that to enter a name you should use standard function std::getline. For example

```
std::getline( std::cin, name );
```

It seems that I have understood what you actually need. Here is a demonstrative program.:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

class Nametele
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string phoneNum;

public:
    Nametele( const std::string &nn, const std::string &phone )
        : name( nn ), phoneNum( phone )
    {

    }

    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    std::string getPhone() const { return phoneNum; }
};

bool operator <( const Nametele &lhs, const Nametele &rhs )
{
    return lhs.getName() < rhs.getName();
}

int main() 
{
    std::list<Nametele> employee;

    employee.push_back(Nametele("acme, sam", "(555) 898-2392"));
    employee.push_back(Nametele("Dolan, edith", "(555) 682-3104"));
    employee.push_back(Nametele("lanfrank, john", "(555), 718-4581"));
    employee.push_back(Nametele("mening, stephen", "(555) 382-7070"));
    employee.push_back(Nametele("zemann, harold", "(555) 219-9912"));

    employee.sort();

    std::cout << "the size of the list is " << employee.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n      name            telephone";
    std::cout << "\n--------------        ----------\n";

    for ( const Nametele &item : employee )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( 14 ) << std::left << item.getName()
                  << "\t      " << item.getPhone() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Enter a name to find: ";

    std::string name;
    std::getline( std::cin, name );

    auto it = employee.begin();

    while ( it != employee.end() && it->getName() != name ) ++it;

    if ( it != employee.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "Employee " << it->getName()
                  << " has phone " << it->getPhone()
                  << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
the size of the list is 5

      name            telephone
--------------        ----------
Dolan, edith          (555) 682-3104
acme, sam             (555) 898-2392
lanfrank, john        (555), 718-4581
mening, stephen       (555) 382-7070
zemann, harold        (555) 219-9912
Enter a name to find: lanfrank, john
Employee lanfrank, john has phone (555), 718-4581
```

Comment: how do i implement this in the program, sorry im really confused

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada If you do not know yet standard algorithms you can use an ordinary loop as I have showed in my post.

Comment: how to use this when i want a user to enter a name and if found the phone number will be display else prompts the user that the name is not found

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada  The methods I have showed returns an iterator that points to the employee if it is found or equal to employee.end(). If it is not equal to employee.end() you can call for it member functions like it->getName() or it->getPhone().

Comment: i try to use your method like this:  std::string name;
    std:: cout << "enter a name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
 
    auto it = employee.begin();
    while ( it != employee.end() && it->getName() != name ) ++it;
 
    if ( it != employee.end() ) std::cout << "Employee " << employee.front().getPhone << " is found\n"; it has some error prog.cpp:57:78: error: invalid use of non-static member function

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada There has to be if ( it != employee.end() ) std::cout << "Employee " << it->getPhone() << " is found\n";

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada Also take into account that you should use function std::getline instead of the operator >>

Comment: i change what you've but error comes : error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::list<Nametele>'

Comment: @Kryssel Tillada See the updated program in my post.

Comment: wow it works thanks it really helps im gonna study your code because its useful